# If my team hasn't killed Herald, can I still pick up the Eye?

Tags: league-of-legends

When you kill the Rift Herald, it drops the Rift Herald Eye, that a team member then picks up to use later.

If the other team gets last hit on the Rift Herald, but I push them away, can I pick up the eye, or is the eye locked to the team that last hitted, as tradition is in LoL?

Also, if they don't pick it up, how long is it available for?

Comment: It's locked to the team that killed it, you can however walk over it and destroy it (so the enemy can't pick it) . I'm not sure exactly how long it stays on the group though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot pick up the Eye of the Herald if your team wasn't the team that killed the Rift Herald. But denying it is still good as they will only get the 200 experience and 25 gold for killing it and not be able to push your turrets with it. If no one steps on it, it will remain on the ground for 40 seconds before disappearing.

source- personal experience and testing with the training tool.